# How do i avoid writing these 3 lines twice?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, protocols

considering the following extensions in SwiftUI:

```
extension Text{
   func applyBG() -> some View {
      self
         .padding(20)
         .background(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.22).cornerRadius(10))
         .foregroundColor(.white)
   }
}

extension TextField{
   func applyBG() -> some View {
      self
         .padding(20)
         .background(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.22).cornerRadius(10))
         .foregroundColor(.white)
   }
}
```

I feel like i could write this better, avoiding repetition.
I could probably solve this with something like:

```
extension View{
   func applyBG() -> some View {
      self
         .padding(20)
         .background(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.22).cornerRadius(10))
         .foregroundColor(.white)
   }
}
```

But i do not want all my views to be able to call this method.
I just want Text and Textfield to have such method. I tried with protocol and associatedType, but i was not able to write these lines just one time in order to achieve clean code.
Any hint or pseudo code on how i could achieve the DRY ?

Comment: Why you do not use a modifier for this job? and then you do not need use a custom protocol like in the answer! a modifier could be used on any View you like!

Comment: I do no want every view to be able to call .viewModifier(BGModifier()) @swiftPunk

Comment: they never call it by them self unless you call it explicitly

Comment: @swiftPunk this is called defensive programming. Lets say im in a shared codebase, and that call on a "not allowed" object can cause sideffects, how would you handle that? I use modifier and i know they are great, but if you want to restrict them, you simply cant

Comment: Cost is protocol conformance, a pattern which is used a lot in swift. Wouldnt be worse make some objects able to call a method they should not ? I get your point, and im trying to identify what is clean and what is not. 1)Code repetion was not clean, and we achieved it 2) Restrict a protocol to just some views by using a protocol conformance, which solved my original request: restriction 3) Going for a view modifier, you dont restrict, and you create a new struct conforming (guess what) a protocol. I dont think protocol are that bad, you always end up using them in  some way, no?

Comment: look at your question! you wanted do an extension for View, the thing that you were looking to do was a modifier for View, but if you feel using custom protocol is better for you then as i said before you do you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Protocol like so:

```swift
import SwiftUI

protocol BGApplyable where Self: View {}

extension BGApplyable {
  func applyBG() -> some View {
    self
     .padding(20)
     .background(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.22).cornerRadius(10))
     .foregroundColor(.white)
  }
}
```

Decide which views can adopt the protocol:

```swift
extension TextField: BGApplyable {}
extension Text: BGApplyable {}
```

Then use it:

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    Text("Foo")
      .applyBG()
    TextField("Hello", text: .constant("World!"))
      .applyBG()
  }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely what i was looking for. I was focusing on associatedType for the protocol, when i could simple restrict my protocol to be used only by views. In fact, using protocol BGApplyable: View {} produced the same result as your. I knew protocol extension could make the trick, thank you for the simplest and most effective answer

Comment: @Simone: using a modifier would be the simplest and most effective answer, not adapting a custom protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the function on a protocol, just change its return type from `some View` to `AnyView`, then make `Text` and `TextField` conform to this protocol.

```
protocol TextView: View {
    func applyBackground() -> AnyView
}

extension TextView {
    func applyBackground() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(padding(20)
                    .background(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0.22).cornerRadius(10))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
        )
    }
}

extension Text: TextView {}
extension TextField: TextView {}

Text("text").applyBackground()
```

Comment: Point is, the views adopting the protocol dont need any further customization, so the func signature in the protocol could be omitted. Also, i was literally trying to avoid AnyView. Thank you anyway!